# JavaScript Api geo processing - internal server error 500

Tags: arcgis-server, geoprocessing, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I am trying to run a geo-processing task using Java Script API for ArcGIS. I have created a simple buffer task, published using ArcGIS server (synchronous) and used the same (almost) code as the [view shed example](http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/arcgisserver/apis/javascript/arcgis/demos/geoprocessor/gp_viewshed.html) . The view shed runs fine, but it fails with my REST service with the following error.

> Server Error - Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>   Code: 500

.

I have browsed a lot and did some changes with respect but nothing seems to work.
Has anyone experienced this?

Comment: >there was a bug where the Rest API could not return geometry for true curves. It was fixed in service pack 1 for 9.3.

Comment: It's difficult to pinpoint the issue (malformed request, etc) if you don't post code.